# Как сделать тест для middleware?

Tags: laravel

Открывать страницу /create можно только для тех, кто залогинился

```
 Route::get('/create', 'ImagesController@create')->middleware('user');
```

Делаю такой тест, но он будет работать, только если убрать посредника из роута

```
 public function testCreateImgTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/create');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Я не знаю, как это сделать для middleware.

Comment: А что делает данный middleware?

Comment: проверяет авторизирован ли пользователь

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 варианта:

1 - Использовать трейт `WithoutMiddleware` в классе. Все middleware будут отключены, тестироваться будет остальная часть приложения.

2 - Использовать авторизацию в тесте. В таком случае, вам нужно будет сделать следующее:

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
Auth::login($user);
```

Таким образом, мы будем действовать из аккаунта `$user`.